# Merge two dataframes based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have these two dataframes:

```
sp_client 
     ConnectionID  Value
0     CN01493292    495
1     CN01492424    440
2     CN01491959    403
3     CN01493200    312
4     CN01493278    282
..           ...    ...
110   CN01492864      1
111   CN01492513      1
112   CN01492899      1
113   CN01493010      1
114   CN01493032      1
[115 rows x 2 columns]

sp_server 
     ConnectionID Value
1     CN01491920     2
1     CN01491920     2
3     CN01491922     2
3     CN01491922     2
5     CN01491928     2
..           ...   ...
595   CN01493166     3
595   CN01493166     3
595   CN01493166     3
597   CN01493163     2
597   CN01493163     2
[673 rows x 2 columns]
```

I would like to merge them in a way where `sp_client['Value']` increments by addition of  `sp_sever['Value']` and `sp_client['Value']` only when the rows satisfy the condition `sp_sever['ConnectionID']==sp_client['ConnectionID']`.

It was a little bit complicated for me but I tried the following, but I am missing the condition part. Maybe it does not need to be merged in the first place. Happy to hear suggestions.

Comment: sp_server don't have unique values, you like to add client into server or other way round?

Comment: concat/append tables on each other, later group them by `ConnectionID`, suming `Value` column if I understood your request correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per my comment, try to append tables and group them by ID while summing Value column as per example:

```
all_data = pd.concat([sp_server,sp_client])
all_data = all_data.groupby('ConnectionID')['Value'].agg(sum).reset_index()
```

out:

```
  ConnectionID  Value
0   CN01491920      4
1   CN01491922      4
2   CN01491928      2
3   CN01491959    403
4   CN01492424    440
5   CN01493200    312
```

Comment: I got this error: 

```TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'```

Comment: check if what datatype is your column `value`, it should be integer